# Как удалить элементы массива по условию?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Есть функция, которая возвращает массив чисел кратных 5:

```js
const multiple = (n, maxNum) => {
  let listOfYers = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < maxNum; i++) {
    if (i % n === 0) {
      listOfYers.push(i);
    }
  }
  return listOfYers;
};
let arrayYears = multiple(5, 1000);
```

По условию числа кратные 100 нужно удалить, кроме тех, которые кратные 500. То есть, 100, 200, 300, 400, 600, 700, 800, 900 нужно удалить с массива

Написал такую ф-ю:

```js
const multipleOfHundred = arrayYears.filter((i) => {
  if (i % 100 === 0 && !(i % 500 === 0)) {
    console.log(i);
  }
});
```

Условие работает правильно, осталось только удалить эти элементы с массива
Как это можно сделать? Буду благодарен за помощь)

Comment: Вы посмотрите как работает filter и что внутри должно быть прописано

Answer (score 1):

```
Я правильно наверное понял
```

```js
let nums = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000]
let findNumber = nums.filter(num => !(num % 500))
console.log(findNumber)
```

Comment: Ну filter же переписывает исходный массив. Лучше уже  через цикл запушить новый. А ещё лучше в условиях прописать, что бы те что кратные 500 пушились в отдельный массив.

Comment: Тут же filter будет возвратить новый массив , в котором будут содержатся только числа  кратные 500, а переменная останется таким же. Может я не правильно понял что-то.

Comment: Да да, это я не прав, filter создаёт новый массив

Comment: Ответ неполный. Этот код удалит только числа, кратные 500, при этом оставит не только числа, кратные 100.

Answer (score 0):

Первый вариант - фильтруем массив.

```js
const multiple = (n, maxNum) => {
  let listOfYers = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < maxNum; i++) {
    if (i % n === 0) {
      listOfYers.push(i);
    }
  }
  return listOfYers;
};
const arrayYears = multiple(5, 1000);

// записываем условие для фильтра в виде функции
const filterExpresion = (year) => !(year % 100 === 0 && !(year % 500 === 0));

// фильтруем
const filteredArray = arrayYears.filter(filterExpresion);

console.log(filteredArray);
```

Второй вариант - сразу же фильтруем массив в момент создания

```js
const multiple = (n, maxNum) => {
  let listOfYers = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < maxNum; i++) {
    // добавляем фильтр в момент создания массива
    if (i % n === 0 && !(i % 100 === 0 && !(i % 500 === 0))) {
      listOfYers.push(i);
    }
  }
  return listOfYers;
};
const arrayYears = multiple(5, 1000);

console.log(arrayYears);
```

Answer (score -1):

Для краткости записи можно так, если планируется просто вычистить массив от лишнего (это пример, функцию "e" подставить свою):

```js
let MyArray = [1,2,3,4,5]

MyArray = [].concat(MyArray.filter(e => e > 2))

console.log(MyArray)
```